# Feats for an Advanced, Mindless Plant Creature

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, monsters, character-advancement

So for story purposes I'm advancing a CR 2 Plant Creature called a [Yellow Musk Creeper](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/yellow-musk-creeper-tohc) to a CR 20.

Now when I read over the rules of advancement, they talked about giving the advanced creature feats. Now as a mindless creature I'm not sure what feats would be beneficial/are legal for it to acquire.

Comment: Its similar but while that is asking if they can in general, this question is more towards what they can get and what would be usefull for them to have.

Comment: They can't get *any* beyond the ones they already have, so the point is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically speaking, as the GM, you can advance and modify any creature however you want.  The Pathfinder SRD has some [guidelines for customizing and creating monsters](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-creation). In short, you change its ability scores and hit dice, and then select feats and features accordingly. For your custom Yellow Musk Creeper, start by **assigning it an Intelligence score**, thereby giving **one feat per odd-numbered HD**.

The "Creature Hit Dice" table on the linked website says that a CR 20 plant would have around 34 hit dice (which means 17 feats), although you can reduce that number if it seems too high. Alternatively, you could start with the hit dice and base statistics for a lower CR, and then add creature templates to raise the CR up to 20.

When choosing feats, you should aim for abilities that seem plausible and thematically appropriate for a plant monster. It could reasonably have Weapon Focus and Toughness, but probably would not have social or magic feats. As for legality, the main restriction is that **a creature can't take a feat if it doesn't meet the prerequisites**.

I recommend simple feats that boost physical attributes, damage output, and saving throws.  For reference, a Mandragora has Lightning Reflexes, and a Treant has a chain of feats that enhance its slam attack.  You also have access to monster feats from the bestiaries; the Pollen Spray feature is arguably a special attack, so why not give it "Ability Focus (Pollen Spray)" to raise the DC of the saving throw?

For more examples, you may want to skim through a [list of plant creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants) to get a sense of which combat capabilities seem sensible for plants.

Comment: +1, One thing which may be worth elaborating about is that without an int score, the plant won't gain any feats from the HD increase - You did describe and emphasis one way to bypass that (another is to give the plant bonus feats), but as the question is currently phrased, it isn't obvious that *not* gaining feats is the default option...